# Flutter Future Async Function - await stuck

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am calling a Future function that should add a document to firestore first, then to retrieve the doc id, then update the doc again with some paramaters.

I need to show a dialog for success or faliure.
it is working fine for success case, but incorrect when testing failure .. I disconnect the internet before pressing the button then I press it to call the future function while internet is off to test failure scenario.

the problem is the future function stuck on the trying to add the document to firestore, it never fail and go to the failure scenario.

the below is future function code:

```
 Future CreateAccount() async {
  CollectionReference businessprofilescollectionref =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('BusinessProfilesCollection');

  DocumentReference docRef = await businessprofilescollectionref.add({
    'Profile_city': bpaddSelectedcity,
    'Profile_direct_category': directcategory,
  });

  if (docRef.id.isEmpty) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => FailureDialog(context));
  }
  if (docRef.id.isNotEmpty) {
    String documentid = docRef.id.toString();
    print(documentid);
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
      Reference ref = storage
          .ref()
          .child("BusinessProfileImages/$documentid".toString());
      UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(bpaddimagefile);
      final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
      print("Image Uploaded");
      final urldownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      print(urldownload);
      businessprofilescollectionref
          .doc(documentid)
          .update({'Profile_image_link': urldownload});
      print("Link Updated");
      await showDialog(
          context: context, builder: (_) => SuccessDialog(context));
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    }
 }
```

I tried to use timeout method like the below, this made the await ends, however the whole Future function is aborted and it doesn't continue executing the commands of showing the failure dialoge.

```
 DocumentReference docRef = await businessprofilescollectionref.add({
    'Profile_city': bpaddSelectedcity,
    'Profile_direct_category': directcategory,
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 20));
```

how can I solve this? I need to try to add the data to database, if that fails, I need to go to failure scenario and show a dialog.

Comment: Could you clarify what the failure scenario is?

Comment: Failure scenario, is for instance user lost internet before pressing the button, I am testing that be disabling wifi then pressing the button. in that case, I need the addition to firestore to fail, and show dialog to user saying faild, please check internet connection.

Comment: Okay, got it. I think you're checking it wrongly with `docRef.id.isEmpty`. You need a try-catch wrapped around the Firestore operation.

Comment: I understand the try and catch block, tried it but I guess it stucks in trying. would be thankful if you can write your suggested code.

Answer (score 1):

## What went wrong:

You're checking if the ID of the `DocumentReference` is empty and using that as your failure scenario.

That will not work because when you get a `DocumentReference` back, it will have an ID. Here is a quote from the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html#:%7E:text=If%20no%20path%20is%20provided%2C%20an%20auto%2Dgenerated%20ID%20is%20used.):

> Returns a DocumentReference with an auto-generated ID, after
> populating it with provided data.

The above reason is why the `docRef.id.isEmpty` if statement is never executed because the ID is never empty.

## How to fix it:

You should use a `try-catch` to wrap the `add` operation and implement the error scenario in the catch block.

Then you continue the rest of the operation in the `docRef.id.isNotEmpty` if statement right under the `try-catch`.

Update your `CreateAccount` function to this below:

```dart
Future CreateAccount() async {
  try {
    CollectionReference businessprofilescollectionref =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('BusinessProfilesCollection');

    DocumentReference docRef = await businessprofilescollectionref.add({
      'Profile_city': bpaddSelectedcity,
      'Profile_direct_category': directcategory,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => FailureDialog(context));
    return;
  }

  String documentid = docRef.id.toString();
  print(documentid);
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref = storage.ref().child("BusinessProfileImages/$documentid".toString());
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(bpaddimagefile);
  final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
  print("Image Uploaded");
  final urldownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  print(urldownload);
  businessprofilescollectionref.doc(documentid).update({'Profile_image_link': urldownload});
  print("Link Updated");
  await showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => SuccessDialog(context));
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, will try that again. But that way, won’t the code under try and catch be executed in both cases? (Success and Failure too)? 
What will stop the rest of code execution after catching the error?

Comment: You're right. The code is missing a return statement in the catch block. I've updated now.